# Ошибка при указании относительного пути к изображению в файле scss

Tags: laravel-mix

Laravel Mix выдает ошибку на тестовом коде, хотя изображение есть.

**Файл `webpack.mix.js`**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/test.scss', 'public/css')
  .version();
```

**Файл `resources/assets/sass/test.scss`**:

```
.test {
  // Указан путь относительно самого `test.scss`
  background-image: url('../images/googlei.png');
}
```

Исходное изображение `resources\assets\images\googlei.png` существует. Текст ошибки:

```
95 % emitting
ERROR Failed to compile with 2 errors 22: 24: 18

error in ./resources/assets/images/googlei.png
Module build failed: Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
...

error in ./resources/assets/sass/test.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
...

npm ERR!code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!errno 2
npm ERR!@ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR!Exit status 2
```

Если в `test.scss` указать неверный путь, например, `googlei.pnggg`, то выдаст:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors  

This relative module was not found:
../images/googlei.pnggg in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--4-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-5!./resources/assets/sass/test.scss

ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/test.scss
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/googlei.pnggg' in 'C:\OSPanel\domains\testdomain\resources\assets\sass'
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена:

1. Удалением **node_modules**.
2. `npm cache clean --force`.
3. `npm install`.